# jQuery get option value in absolute

Tags: jquery

i'm get user lists in database with jquery ajaxt and create `select` tag with it , after putting this tag into html tag i cant get option selectable value in absolute.

**HTML:**

```
<td>
   <span id='author_name'></span>
</td>
```

**jquery:**

```
  $.post("model/controller.php", {postaction:'getUserList'}, 
        function(data){
            userList = data.userList;
            author_name = "<ul class='styledlist' ><select id='userList' style='height:26px;width:110px;margin-right:-8px;' >"
            $.each(userList,function( i , item ){
                author_name += "<option value='" + userList[i].id + "' >" + userList[i].username +"</option>";
            });
            author_name += "</select></ul>";
            $("#author_name").html(author_name);
        },'json');
  $('#submenu_1_1').click(function(){
            $("#tab_content").on('author_name', function(event){
                alert( $(this).val() );
            });                
  });
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do here? `author_name` is not an event, but the ID of the element, which is a span, that doesnt' have a value ?

Comment: what type of data coming into data variable? is it json encoded? if yes then it is to be userlist = $.parseJSON(data); if data is not in json format are you sure that it is going in that $.each ? I want to know does really data.userList exist and has some values?

Comment: @VivekMuthal, `data.userList` is json format and it is not my problem, my problem is get option value, `select` can create successfull in `$.each`

Comment: @mahdipishguy i asked because the code seems fine and there is no error, only while adding option the html could be get garbled and because of that select is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebind the `click()` function *after* you insert the `<select>` into the DOM, for the `<select>`, you need to use the `change` event instead. Change this:

```
$("#author_name").html(author_name);
```

to this:

```
$("#author_name").html(author_name)
$("#userList").on("change",function(){
   alert( $(this).val() );
});
```

Comment: not work,`$("#author_name").val()` return empty, in old version of jquery i cant try with `.live()` but i cant use `.on` in latst version

Comment: [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is for jQuery 1.7 and newer. You should not be using any version of jQuery older than 1.7.